# Suggested order for the Redwall series?

Tags: suggested-order, redwall

What is the most correct order in which to read Brian Jacques's series of *Redwall* books?

I read most or all of them when I was younger, but would like to know how to order them in case I ever return for a reread.

Comment: There's an even more detailed answer to this question [over here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/207/17) on a sister SE site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two most obvious orders in which to read them.

---

### Chronological order

**The Badger stories, part 1**

- *Lord Brocktree*

  <sup>This is the only book which entirely predates both Redwall Abbey and Martin the Warrior.</sup>

**The Martin stories**

The next three books are set during the time of the legendary Martin the Warrior, who makes ghostly appearances in almost all later books.

- *The Legend of Luke*

  <sup>Although the surrounding story featuring the adult Martin comes after *Martin the Warrior* and *Mossflower*, the central tale of Luke predates both.</sup>
- *Martin the Warrior*

  <sup>Covers Martin's origins pre-Redwall.</sup>
- *Mossflower*

  <sup>Covers the backstory of the establishment of Redwall itself.</sup>

**The Badger stories, part 2**

- *Outcast of Redwall*

  <sup>This is pretty stand-alone, the story of Sunflash the Mace.</sup>

**The Mariel stories**

The next two books are set during the time of Joseph the Bellmaker and his daughter Mariel, somewhere in between Martin's time and Matthias's.

- *Mariel of Redwall*
- *The Bellmaker*

**The Badger stories, part 3**

- *Salamandastron*

  <sup>Another entirely stand-alone story, not even particularly focused on Redwall.</sup>

**The main series**

- *Redwall*

  <sup>The first Redwall book to be published.</sup>
- *Mattimeo*

  <sup>A sequel, Mattimeo being the son of Matthias, the hero of *Redwall*.</sup>
- *The Pearls of Lutra*

  <sup>Featuring Mattimeo's son Martin and the hedgehog Tansy (the first Redwall book I read).</sup>
- *The Long Patrol*

  <sup>A sequel to *The Pearls of Lutra*, featuring Tansy as the abbess and also Cregga Rose Eyes.</sup>
- *Marlfox*

  <sup>Linked to the previous book by the character of Cregga.</sup>
- *The Taggerung*

  <sup>Again linked by Cregga - this is the final book featuring her.</sup>
- *Triss*

  <sup>Set long after the previous book; Skipper mentions the Taggerung as his distant ancestor.</sup>
- *Loamhedge*
- *Rakkety Tam*
- *High Rhulain*
- *Eulalia!*
- *Doomwyte*
- *The Sable Quean*

  <sup>(Yes, that title is spelled correctly.)</sup>
- *The Rogue Crew*

  <sup>Published posthumously.</sup>

---

### Release order

- *Redwall* (1986)
- *Mossflower* (1988)
- *Mattimeo* (1989)
- *Mariel of Redwall* (1991)
- *Salamandastron* (1992)
- *Martin the Warrior* (1993)
- *The Bellmaker* (1994)
- *Outcast of Redwall* (1995)
- *Pearls of Lutra* (1996)
- *The Long Patrol* (1997)
- *Marlfox* (1998)
- *The Legend of Luke* (1999)
- *Lord Brocktree* (2000)
- *Taggerung* (2001)
- *Triss* (2002)
- *Loamhedge* (2003)
- *Rakkety Tam* (2004)
- *High Rhulain* (2005)
- *Eulalia!* (2007)
- *Doomwyte* (2008)
- *The Sable Quean* (2010)
- *The Rogue Crew* (2011)

---

Resources used: [one](http://redwall.wikia.com/wiki/Redwall_Chronological_Order), [two](http://redwall.wikia.com/wiki/Publication_Order).

Comment: Does chrono-order ruin the "surprise" of mystery you get from reading them in release order? For instance, they changed Narnia to have The Magician's Nephew first, and I always felt explaining the Warddrobe's creation first cheapened the mystery.

Comment: Great formatting the of the list, and I am pleased to see you put "Lord Brocktree" at the top, was about to comment on the other answer in regard to that.

Comment: @CreationEdge I don't think it does, however some people like not knowing the back story of events and characters till quite late in whatever story so I can't speak for everyone.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have them sitting on my shelf in the first order you mentioned. :)

Comment: Good answer though I would strongly suggest reading the Legend of Luke after Mossflower.

Comment: @CreationEdge I read *The Magician's Nephew* first, so can't comment re Narnia :-) As for Redwall, I read them in the closest approximation I could manage to release order, but the only ones I can think of that might benefit from being read out of order are *Matthias* (when he was still setting up the world and hadn't got all the details straight yet) and, as ibid mentioned, *The Legend of Luke* (part of which is set after *Mossflower*, with the main story being a sort of extended flashback taking up half the book).

Comment: Good order...  certainly the one I would suggest to others :)

Comment: are you missing redwall in your chronological order list?

Comment: @TylerH Good point. Edited out the spoiler.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR, I would read Redwall first, the story has many "errors" that don't follow future stories. It's meant as the intro, from there you can choose either chronological or published order.

Q&A from Brian Jacques's website [source](http://www.redwall.org/ideas.html)

> Webmaster's note: Although we recommend reading the books in the order
>   in which they were written , the chronological order of the books is:
>   Martin the Warrior
>
> Mossflower
>
> The Legend of Luke
>
> Outcast of Redwall
>
> Mariel of Redwall
>
> The Bellmaker
>
> Salamandastron
>
> Redwall
>
> Mattimeo
>
> The Pearls of Lutra
>
> The Long Patrol
>
> Marlfox
>
> Lord Brocktree
>
> Taggerung
>
> Triss
>
> Loamhedge
>
> Rakkety Tam
>
> High Rhulain
>
> Eulalia!
>
> Doomwyte

Here is the publication order

> Redwall
>
> Mossflower
>
> Mattimeo
>
> Mariel of Redwall
>
> Salamandastron
>
> Martin the Warrior
>
> Bellmaker
>
> Outcast of Redwall
>
> Pearls of Lutra
>
> Long Patrol
>
> Marlfox
>
> Legend of Luke
>
> Lord Brocktree
>
> Taggerung
>
> Triss
>
> Loamhedge
>
> Rakkety Tam
>
> High Rhulain
>
> Eulalia!
>
> Doomwyte
>
> Sable Quean
>
> Rogue Crew

Comment: Good answer, personally would recommend the chronological order.

Comment: @Theyna Indeed, it's nice to get a quote from Brian Jacques's website (even though there's no link). I've provided a more detailed answer below though. Also, are you the Thaggerung? ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor haha, that wasn't the intention when I picked this name... no dragons for you in Redwall though :p